# How can I build things in Ark which are too heavy for me?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I need to build a [Stone Dinosaur Gateway](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Stone_Dinosaur_Gateway). To build it I need about 280 Stone 140 Wood 100 Thatch. These materials are far too heavy to be in my inventory. I can carry about 150 units and need about 250. How am I supposed to build it? Do I really need to wait 10 levels and put every single point into "weight" (weight goes 10 units up if skilled and one has a single skill-point per level)?

Comment: Use an animal to carry the supplies to where you want to build.

Comment: @KevinFischer And then? I need to have them in my inventory to build the Gateway. Transportation is not a problem but rather having the materials in my very own inventory.

Comment: you can still add things to your inventory and not move (if i remember right, it's been about six months since i've played).  make the gateway, should stay in your inventory and place it where you'd like it to go.

Comment: @KevinFischer Yep, good idea. I've already tried this. However, this is limited to a certain amount. If you are approximately 180/150 you can't add any further materials.

Comment: okay, have you tried accessing your animal's inventory menu, then go to create (i think it's the top left tab) and create something from there?  i can't remember if you can actually create something while in an animal's inventory.

Comment: @KevinFischer Yes, also checked that already. Doesn't work :/

Comment: man, i'm running out of ideas. i think you just need to level up at this point

Comment: @KevinFischer Many thanks anyway :) I guess I need to double-check the "overloading" method. Still sounds valid to me and the PS4 control is not the best. So maybe it was just one of these bugs where you can't move things from the right inventory to your inventory.

Comment: try it while mounted

Comment: place all the crap into the animal's inventory, mount the animal then grab it back to create.  might work

Comment: Beaver. Or overloading should work to about double your carry weight, 150 is fine I build everything I need with that and a beaver (if you're building non-smithy items though you do need the engram to use a beaver or smithy for it but those are dropped all the time). Store everything but the materials as well to help make sure you have enough.

Answer (score 2):

Carry the light resources first, thatch, wood, stone, the stone should only way 90 or so pounds so you should be able to make it to the chest by the time you start to get over weight. If this does not work, make a chest in your general building area and transport the materials by as much as you can carry. You could also use tamed dinosaurs. I tamed a bronto with tranq darts, tranq arrows, a club and a slingshot. I also recommend farming and getting pigs for fertilizer.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, you can overload yourself to just shy of double your maximum carrying capacity, so if you have 150 weight, you can carry about 300ish pounds before you can't put anything else in your inventory.

What you do is put all your resources into a dino (careful not to overload if they're coming with you) or storage bin, and once you've gathered all the resources, pull them all out of the bin/dino and craft away.

After it's done, the resources will be consumed and you're left with just the item, which for building materials is typically only 4 pounds.